# unindent does not match any outer indentation level Coursera assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi guys i just started with Python (3.5) trying to complete an assignment on Coursera  and i keep getting the above error

```
Age = 15
if Age >=15 :
    print ("Highschool")
   else if
       print ("No HighSchool")
```

Comment: Is this Python syntax? `else if` should be `elif:`. And your indentation is off

Comment: My 'unclear what you're asking' close vote came before the edit. Now it's pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

Python, unlike many programming languages, relies on indentation to dictate scope. In particular, it permits tabs or certain number of spaces to indicate scope. Contiguous lines with the same indentation level are all in the same scope.

Your code:

```
Age = 15
if Age >=15 :
    print ("Highschool")
   else if
       print ("No HighSchool")
```

Has indentation that is uneven, which confuses the python interpreter. You seem to be using 4 spaces to indicate indentation, but your `else if` statement (should  be `else:` by the way) is not at any indentation level that  makes sense. You use 3 spaces before the `else if` statement. You should actually be using 0 spaces, as it is operating at the same scope/level of the `if` statement.

```
Age = 15
if Age >=15 :
    print ("Highschool")
else:
    print ("No HighSchool")
```

Read more about Python's whitespace [here](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `else` matching an `if` MUST occur at exactly the same indentation level as the `if`. Also, there's no need for another `if` following the `else`. Try

```
Age = 15
if Age >=15:
    print ("Highschool")
else:
    print ("No HighSchool")
```

You should find that works better· Remember the colons - they are important!